# Creating a mapping of users to groups, and getting the group based on user combinations

Tags: mysql, database

I have a set of user and groups. Users can be part of one or many groups, and groups can have one or many users. So I've got the join table of `user_groups`.

Is there a way I can find out the name of the group, based on an exact combination of users? I'm not positive if the structure I have in place for this would be correct to execute, this, but here are two examples:

The user with ID 1 (Jeff) is part of two groups, as shown by the `user_groups` table. For the one group with ID `2`, he is the only member. And for the other group of ID `4`, he is one of two members.

I'd like to be able to build a query where if I have just his ID, I'll know that the group name is GP-B, because that's the mapping. If I have user IDs `1` and `4`, that maps to group `4`, so I'd know the group name is GP-D.

`SELECT id, name FROM users;`

```
1, Jeff
2, John
3, Mary
4, Jen
5, Mike
```

`SELECT id, name FROM groups;`

```
1, GP-A
2, GP-B
3, GP-C
4, GP-D
```

`SELECT user_id, group_id FROM user_groups;`

```
1, 2
1, 4
2, 3
4, 1
4, 4
```

The best query I could come up with so far is:

```
SELECT groups.name 
FROM user_groups
LEFT JOIN groups
    ON groups.id = user_groups.group_id
WHERE user_id IN (1,4)
GROUP BY group_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

And that seemed to be working. However, if I did just the single user:

```
SELECT groups.name 
FROM user_groups
LEFT JOIN groups
    ON groups.id = user_groups.group_id
WHERE user_id IN (1)
GROUP BY group_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

It ends up pulling both groups he's part of, so something is incorrect about my query.

Comment: Not the answer, but here is a sql fiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/58596/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to move the `WHERE` expression - `user_id IN (1)` - in the JOIN condition:

```
SELECT groups.name 
FROM user_groups
LEFT JOIN groups
    ON groups.id = user_groups.group_id AND user_id IN (1)
GROUP BY group_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 AND groups.name IS NOT NULL;
```

(and set a filter in the HAVING clause so that you will exclude NULL groups - those that didn't match)

This way you will get **all rows** from `user_groups` and then you will be able to make sure that the count will get the exact number of records that you inputted.

In your initial query, the `WHERE` clause filters out some rows so you can't actually correctly count how many members are in each group (because you exclude those that don't match your filter).

Comment: You are a wizard. Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!